# Matshita UJDA 760 DVD/CDRW not working

Tags: dvd

I have a Panasonic Toughbook CF-30 with a Matshita UJDA 760 DVD/CDRW running Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried everything I can think of to try and resolve this issue but nothing works. The drive shows up in the disk utility and I'm able to eject the dive from here. However the drive can't read anything and won't auto play. I'm running windows 7 paralleled on this machine and the drive works just fine in that. Please help me with this problem. I much prefer your Operating system over Windows and must be able to use this CD drive for work.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe something to do with CDFS.  Try this.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cdfs-src
```